# Tried to load twitter bootstrap, now getting a funny error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I just ran:

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```

and then tried to run a rails server, and got this weird error:

```
rails s
/Users/makersacademy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:33:in `pwd': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/makersacademy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:33:in `<module:Noexec>'
    from /Users/makersacademy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/makersacademy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
```

Can someone help? I don't know what I need to do to get the rails server working... Thanks!

Comment: did you add the gem file and run bundle install?

Comment: @Pigueiras from the paths it looks like the OP is on OS X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Really silly. It was answered here:

http://shriikant.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/shell-init-error-retrieving-current.html

You just need to do cd and then go back in and it seems to resolve itself... Not sure why...